# The method 'add' isn't defined for the type 'Future'. Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'add'

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to retrieve metadata from files and add them to a List, I that list to be Future because I want to use it in a FutureBuilder.
Here is my function that gets metadata and loads it into a list:

```dart
Future<void> _loadAudioFiles() async {
  audioFiles = await audioFileService.getAudioFiles();
  for (String audioFile in audioFiles) {
    int index = audioFiles.indexOf(audioFile);
    String title = audioFile.split('/').last;
    //remove .mp3 from title
    title = title.substring(0, title.length - 4);

    MetadataRetriever.fromFile(File(audioFile)).then((metadata) {
      setState(() {
        tracks.add(Track(audioFile, title, index, metadata));
      });
        audioPlayerService.setPlaylist(tracks as List<Track>);
      
    });
  }
}
```

And my futureBuilder

```dart
FutureBuilder(
      future: tracks,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return TrackListWidget(
          tracks: snapshot.data as List<Track>,
          onTrackTap: (Track track) {       
            if(track.index != audioPlayerService.getCurrentIndex()){
              audioPlayerService.play(track.index, seek: true);
            }else{
              audioPlayerService.play(track.index, seek: false);
            }

            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => AudioPlayScreen( audioFilePath: track.path, tracks: snapshot.data!, startingIndex: track.index),
              ),
            );
          },
        );
        } else {
          return const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }
      },
    );
```

I have tried rewritting my `_loadFromFiles()` method, but I stumbled upon other problem
which is that `loadedTracks` list is not accesible outside for loop. Inside it has all data needed but outside its empty.

New method:

```dart
Future<void> _loadAudioFiles() async {
  print('_loadAudioFiles called');
  audioFiles = await audioFileService.getAudioFiles();
  List<Track> loadedTracks = [];
  for (String audioFile in audioFiles) {
    int index = audioFiles.indexOf(audioFile);
    String title = audioFile.split('/').last;
    //remove .mp3 from title
    title = title.substring(0, title.length - 4);

    try {
      var metadata = await MetadataRetriever.fromFile(File(audioFile));
      loadedTracks.add(Track(audioFile, title, index, metadata));
    } catch (e) {
      print('error loading metadata for $audioFile: $e');
    }
  }

  print('loaded tracks: $loadedTracks');
  tracks = Future.value(loadedTracks);
  audioPlayerService.setPlaylist(loadedTracks);
  setState(() {
    // update state here
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correct. But it seems that you have a function that loads files (takes a long time) and you want to update the UI as each track metadata is added.

In that case, FutureBuilder is not the way to go. What you should do is use a [StreamBuilder](https://dart.dev/articles/libraries/creating-streams#creating-a-stream-from-scratch) as it provides a way to receive a sequence of events, in your case metadata.

This may not be the best implementation but it will give you an idea on how to accomplish what you want:

```dart
Stream<List<String>> _loadAudioFiles() async* {
    List<String> tracks = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
      tracks.add('Loaded $i');
      yield tracks;
    }
  }
```

And you use StreamBuilder like this:

```dart
StreamBuilder(
    stream: _loadAudioFiles(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
        print(snapshot.data.toString());
        return Column(
            children: [Text(snapshot.data.toString())],
            );
        } else {
                    return const Text('Loading...');
               }
         },
   )
```